# How can I enforce my code conventions on line breaks in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, prettier, ktlint, ktfmt

**Is there any formatting options available in either ktlint, ktfmt, diktat, prettier or other linter that can help me achieve this (see below)?**

This is the format that I desire (rewritten for this purpose, focus on formatting - not the logic):

```kotlin
fun foo() {
    return true && ("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ==
        "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd")
}
```

*Comment: This style is more compact where I would want a line break if the content doesn't fit and add as many "whole" expressions as possible on the previous line before making the line break*

But my lint formatter (ktlint) wants this format:

```kotlin
fun foo() {
    return true && (
        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ==
        "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
    )
}
```

*Comment: An unwanted line break is added right after the left parenthesis*

What I have tried: Most options in ktlint that include the keywords "parenthesis", "line break", etc.

My current .editorconfig:

```
[*]
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[{*.kt,*.kts}]
ij_kotlin_code_style_defaults = KOTLIN_OFFICIAL
ij_kotlin_continuation_indent_in_if_conditions = false
```